# Is there a name for the collection of languages that a person is proficient in?

Tags: list-of-languages

I have been trying to find an accurate term for it. I speak three different languages and couldn't find an appropriate term in any of them. I have thought of:

- Mastered languages

Comment: No there is not a word for it. Mastery is a big word. languages spoken, I'd say and list them. And beware of trilingual as they implies **equal** levels in all three. :)

Comment: What about _**glottotheke**_, Greek _γλῶττα_ (glôtta, “language”)  +‎ -_θήκη_ (-thḗkē, “box, chest”), by analogy with ‘biblotheke’?

Comment: That's a cool suggestion @YellowSky

Comment: No one would say I have a collection of languages I speak. It's just not said.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such term, at least there is no well-known term. I'd use *repertoire of languages* or *language repertoire* when I  were in need to talk about it.

EDIT: Alternatively, I'd just say *Person X speaks N languages* or *Person X speaks ⟨list of languages⟩* avoiding to use a noun for the set of languages.

Comment: repertoire of languages does not imply a person speaks them. It could be a list. [avoid using//when I need to talk about it]